# Is it better to paginate on the server side or front end?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building Laravel + Vue app and I am wondering, whether it is better to use pagination on the back-end or front-end? I assume that it is better to send request with as least data as possible per page, but I would like to hear your comments.

Comment: If you gonna have 10m records, what do you think will happen if you paginate via any brand browser (front-end)? You should ask this your colleagues instead of random people on street. (The answer to your question is backend in most cases.)

Comment: annoyed they closed this question, would have loved to get some more perspectives on when one is beneficial over the other.

Answer (score 20):

It is A Tradeoff, Each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.

**For Server Side Pagination:**

1. your request time and data are reduced, as only a selected no of rows will be sent by the server.
2. browser required less memory hence faster to process like filter, map, reduce etc.(only for one page)

**For Client Side Pagination:**

1. As all data is present on client machine user can easily switch between back and forth.
2. filter, search, map, reduce is possible on whole data.
3. server get few requests as for search, filter, etc needed extra request and many iterations to the server.

So choose according to your specific requirements.

### Update - example

In 90% of cases, taking best of both worlds works more efficiently for example-

Load most relevant data and paginate over browser. like Invoices in one accounting year. but for this you need to make the design of the application more complex like adding ability to switch accounting year in my example. but the use case in this invoice and accounting year example is most of the time user require data of one accounting year and then process it like filter by customer; sort by date etc. so in here backend filters the data according to accounting year and send to the client browser. browser can again sort, filter the limited data quickly, according to user's action. only 10 lines were displayed in table with pagination.

"Identify the use case" is the gist here.